# Use an object, before it's created

Tags: c#, forms, dynamic

I want on a listBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event,
to dynamically create a few controls [labels and trackbars]
now before I want to create those, I need to delete all labels and trackbars.

Not on every listbox `SelectedIndexChanged` event there need to be generated as much labels and textboxes.
How do I make sure, that every time the event is called 
the price amount of controls were created.

Current thought: delete trackbar and labels, than create them, but of course you will get an error saying, trackbar/label does not exist.

Code I thought of so far:

```
if (trackbar != null)
{
    trackBar.Dispose();
}

for (int i = 0; i < calc; i++)
{

    Label Label = new Label();
    Label.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + a++;
    Label.Text = "Board -" + a + "- Height:";
    Label.Location = new Point(10, 450 + (50 * c));
    Label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
    this.Controls.Add(Label);

    TrackBar trackBar = new TrackBar();
    trackBar.Name = "TrackbarWidth" + c++;
    trackBar.Maximum = 85;
    trackBar.Minimum = 65;
    trackBar.SmallChange = 5;
    trackBar.TickFrequency = 5;
    trackBar.Value = 65;
    trackBar.Location = new Point(150, 450 + (50 * c));
    trackBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
    TrackBarAdded.Insert(0, trackBar);
    this.Controls.Add(trackBar);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply before create, iterate through all form controls of type trackbar and dispose it

```
foreach(TrackBar t in this.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>())
{
   t.Dispose();
}
```

if you have any controls that you don't want to be removed, you can use it's Tag property to add some flag value which will help you to mark which control you don't want to remove

```
Ex: 
     Label a = new Label();
     a.Tag = "non-disposal";
     Label b = new Label();

     foreach(Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
     {
         if(l.Tag.ToString()!="non-disposal")
             l.Dispose();
     }
```

so `Label a` wont be removed, rather than `b`

Comment: It does work, but i have some trackbars on my form that i don't want to get removed. any help? ones that are not dynamicly created

Comment: @user1859829 this code just iterate through trackbar controls, labels are not affected

Comment: I changed trackbar to label, since i need labels and trackbars that are dynamicly created to be deleted. So if i had an trackbar that i didn't want to get deleted (one that is not dynamicly created) would still be deleted. thank you for your response.

Comment: It doesn't work, i am getting a error saying "object reference not set to an instance of an object"